# Pull out chunks of a plot made in python and re-display

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I have made a plot in jupyter that has an x-axis spanning for about 40 seconds. I want to pull out sections that are milliseconds long and re-display them as separate plots (so that they can be better viewed). How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You could use some subplots, and slice the original data arrays. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,40,1000)
y = np.random.random(1000)

fig, [ax1,ax2,ax3] = plt.subplots(3,1)

ax1.plot(x,y)
ax2.plot(x[100:120],y[100:120])
ax3.plot(x[500:520],y[500:520])

plt.show()
```

[image]